# How can I find the IP address history of my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, ip-address

Is it possible to view a history of the IP addresses that have logged into my Gmail account?

Comment: While it won't show IP addresses, your [Google Account Activity](https://www.google.com/settings/activity) will show from what countries and with what browsers and operating systems your account has been accessed. You can change the time-period being examined as well.

Answer (score 10):

Look at the bottom right hand side of the page when you're logged into Gmail. You can see "Last account activity: xx minutes ago Details". Click on the ["Details" link](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=4d4ff08391&view=ac) to get a list of IP address and locations of access to your account.

Comment: but they give only 10 ip addresses .. what if i want an entire day or atleast last 100 .. is there a way ? please let me know.

Comment: Good, but can I get a longer list?